# Does OB-RM support, "If A is good, and if B then A, then B is good"?

Tags: deontic-logic

[**OB**-RM is a proposition in deontic logic according to which](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-deontic/#SDLSynt):

[image]

Now I was trying to work with a different moral operator *g* for "it is good that,"<sup>**W**</sup> and I wanted to be able to show that:

- (*gA* & (*B* then *A*)) then *gB*

Maybe I'm confused but that kind of looks like, "If A then B; B; therefore A," but I also am assuming that if *gA* then *ggA* (and *vice versa*<sup>**X**</sup>), so I don't know (I don't know why the assumption seems to me to be relevant). So I tried looking over this slightly adjusted formulation of such an argument:

[image]

That still looks invalid, or at least gappy, though. As for what I'm searching for, I feel like **OB**-RM is a similar move for **OB**, so can I adapt that to *g* to get the result I'm aiming for? (My motivation is that I would like to show in my system that it is good to be helpful when it comes to other good, i.e. helpfulness can be meta-good; maybe I'm trying to use more machinery than I need for such a conclusion.)

---

<sup>**W**</sup>See Rebuschi[[08](https://hal.science/hal-00351729/document)]. Incidentally, it seems per that formulation that *g* is vulnerable to the contrary-to-duty problem, so yet another intuition of mine is that my own analysis needs to cope with that problem to deliver the "right (or at least target) result."

<sup>**X**</sup>Greve[[11](https://philpapers.org/archive/VANWTI)] critiques this kind of proposition (the conclusion of the paper being, roughly, that it is useless or false).

Comment: nice question ha

Comment: You do not want "gA & (B then A)) then gB". Take A="peace on Earth" and B="all humans are dead". Evil may well produce some good, "*I am part of that force that always wills the evil and always produces the good*", as Mephistofeles said. What you may want is "gA & (no A without B)) then gB", but "no A without B" is "if A then B", not "if B then A". I suspect that even that will run into trouble with if-then as the material conditional, but at least it is not as overt.

Comment: @Conifold that wouldn't involve a moral equivocation re: "peace on Earth"? For wouldn't we normally use that phrase to refer to a state where there are people? But I admit that I have no clear standard for constructing chains of actions in the right fine-grained way, so as to block such unfortunate conditions from being part of a morally salient chain. (I haven't studied event-individuation enough, for example, I think.)

Comment: I don't see how you would get to there from OB-RM. OB-RM just states that from "p entails q" it follows that "if p is obligatory then q is obligatory". It means that obligations carry through to their logical consequences. It is not concerned with which antecedents might make a proposition obligatory (or good). Your ==> would need to be causal to make any sense. If it were a material conditional, then trivially all kinds of B's would be good, including contradictions.

Comment: @Bumble yeah, I can't see how to get there... I've been doing a silly Substack thing and I made a post there about this attempt at a "helpfulness theorem" and it's the first post I felt I had to outright delete instead of just editing. I had a totally different derivation in mind originally, but I started reading about the *g* operator and all and got sucked into trying to work it out that way :p

Answer (score 1):

In one horror movie, some evil genius asks a lady if she would like to get a million dollar. Of course, she says. Well, says the genius, your husbands airplane is going to crash 10 seconds from now, killing two hundred people, and his life insurance will pay you a million dollars. (From memory, details were different).

Getting a million dollars is good. Two hundred people dying is not good. But if two hundred people die, this one widow to be will get a million dollars.

Comment: This is a good(!) proposed counterexample, although I wonder if getting a million dollars is good. Moreover, I would question having the plane crash be *B*; one might locate *B* at, "The insurance company pays out." OTOH we might have, "If the plane crashes, the insurance company pays out," as another *B* to *gA* pipeline, though... Hmm.